# Implementing a multi-process server in Python, with Twisted

Tags: python, parallel-processing, twisted

I have to write a CPU-bound server in Python, to distribute workloads for many cores. I want to use Twisted as the server (requests coming in via TCP).

Are there any better options - using Ampoule, perhaps? I also saw an article using Twisted's `pb` for communication, in conjunction with Popen - or perhaps combine it with `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Ampoule](https://launchpad.net/ampoule) is a good building block for a multiprocess CPU-bound server.  It uses the simpler AMP protocol, rather than PB (the complexity of which is usually not needed just to move job data into another process and then retrieve the results).  It handles process creation, lifetime management, restarting, etc.

You generally want to avoid using `Popen` or the `multiprocessing` standard library module if you're using Twisted.  They can cooperate, but they both present blocking-oriented APIs which somewhat defeat the purpose of using Twisted in the first place.  Twisted's native child process API, [`reactor.spawnProcess`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) is as capable and avoids blocking.  Ampoule is based on this.

Ampoule is not as widely used as `multiprocessing`, though.  You may find it to have some quirks in your development or deployment environments.  I don't think these will be obstacles you can't overcome, though.  I developed a service which used Ampoule to distribute the work of parsing large quantities of HTML across multiple CPUs and it eventually worked fine.  If you do come across any problems though I encourage you to [report them upstream](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ampoule)!  Eventually I would like to be able to say that Ampoule is as robust as anything (or more so) instead of attaching a disclaimer about its use. :)

Comment: thanks for answer, jean-paul! but don't twisted also have AMP? why not use twisted-only amp+spawnProcess and add another library? why don't you then add ampoule to twisted, if it's so good?

Comment: As Jean-Paul says, ampoule is not as robust as `spawnProcess` itself, but it has more features.  The only way it will become more robust is if lots of people use it, report bugs, and help to improve it, so please give it a try so we can add it to Twisted sooner! :)